# Center of Kinect Coordinate System

Tags: kinect

I am working on a Kinect project and need to know the center of the coordinate system of Kinect. I have searched and found no definite working diagrams or spec sheet regarding this. Can anyone help me on this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinate origin should be the the location of your sensor(IR lens I assume). Everything it sees in it's frustum is then viewed as followed:

- X axis is horizontal
- Y axis is vertical
- Z axis is depth (close objects have a small depth value/far objects have a larger depth value)

The depth unit with most sdks is in milimeters

[image: Kinect coordinate system]

You can use a 4x4 transformation matrix to define your custom coordinate system and make adjustments as you need them (e.g. consider the origin in a different location,etc.)